# How is 555 astable timing affected by a resistor on Vcc

Tags: 555

I am trying to build a circuit that will plug in to a cell phone and let me read the value of a thermistor by generating a tone to the microphone, where the frequency is a function of the thermistor's resistance.  I have a prototype in TINA, but my timings are being affected by the resistor on the microphone / power line.
[image: schematic with timing]

I'm using a TLC551 because it tolerates lower voltages than the 555, but the timings should not be affected by this substitution.

The transient analysis shows that I've got a frequency here of less than 1000hz.  For the values I have right now (Ra=5k, Rb=10.27k, C=47nf) I would normally have a frequency of 1200Hz.  Even if I try adding the cellphone resistance to Ra (Ra=7.2K, Rb=10.27k, C=47nf) I should still be getting 1100hz.  If I try remove the resistor in the cellphone section of the schematic, the timings match predicted 555 timings.

So, my conclusion is that putting a resistor in front of the Vcc input to the TLC551 is decreasing frequency.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to work that drop into the timing calculations.  To be able to read the thermistor, I have to be able to work backwards from frequency to deduce Rb.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Where are you getting the DC power for Vcc?  Why isn't the OUT lead of the 555 connected to anything?  Where is the thermistor?

Comment: @tcrosley He's getting the DC power from the electret microphone bias supplied by the phone.

Comment: Thermistor will go where Rb is.  I needed something with a known resistance for prototyping so I just dropped in a resistor there for now

Sphero is correct - dc power from microphone bias.  That's also why I don't need to connect the out pin - the 555 will draw power while charging the capacitors, which will be read as a signal to the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency will be affected by the capacitance on the supply since the reference voltages for oscillation will change during the cycles.

I suggest you may be better off trying to regulate the supply with something like a Vbe multiplier, an LED or a low voltage shunt regulator. Temperature stability is not important, but relatively low shunt impedance is.

Comment: This makes sense.  I can actually see from the plot in the image I attached that the voltage drop across R3 (in the cellphone) varies by nearly 0.4 volts, so I can understand how that would significantly alter the reference voltages.

Answer (score 1):

From my gess is the propagation delay time see the datasheet page 10 and 11. "These delay times add directly to the period and create differences between calculated and actual values that increase with frequency. In addition, the internal on-state resistance ron during discharge adds to RB to provide another source of timing error in the calculation when RB is very low or ron is very high".
you have from the datasheet:
Tc(H) = CT* (RA + RB) * ln[3 - -tPHL/(CT*(RB+ron))] + TPHL
and
Tc(L) = CT*(RB+ ron) *  ln[3 - -tPHL/(CT*(RB+RA))] + TPLH